# How to copy files one by one to different folders?

Tags: shell, directory, filenames, cp

In a directory I have files with the names:

```
01.txt 02.txt 03.txt
```

In the same directory are folders with the names:

```
01.abc 02.def 03.ghi
```

I need a command to copy the files to the folders one by one, so that `01.txt` is in `01.abc`, `02.txt` is in `02.def` and `03.txt` is in `03.ghi`. The command should not consider the names of the folders but fill the folders with the files top down (one file to each folder).

Many thanks!

Edit 1:

I have changed the code from [Move files to multiple folders [closed]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150097/move-files-to-multiple-folders) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

LISTFILESCMD='ls *.txt' 
FQUANTITY=1
FOLDERLIST=`seq -w 1 3`

for FOLDER in $FOLDERLIST; do mv `$LISTFILESCMD | head -n $FQUANTITY`   $FOLDER; done
```

The result is, that the 3 files are in the 3rd folder.

Edit 2:

No, with FQUANTITY=3 the files go in the 1st folder.

With FQUANTITY=1 the script above works.
But it doesn't work right, if the filenames or the foldernames contain spaces.

I have made a second script, which also works with spaces in filenames, but only if the filenames contain a dot, and this script doesn't work, if the foldernames contain spaces. I would like to know, how to make it work also with spaces in foldernames and/or without dots in filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash

array1=(*/) # folder
array2=(*.*) # file

for ((i=0;i<${#array2[@]};++i)); do
    mv "${array2[i]}" "${array1[i]}"
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? What is your use-case? I'm asking, because for 3 files you could potentially do this manually...

Comment: There are more files in the directory. The files here are just an example. The use-case is to copy the files with one click.

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: I tried to ask a question.

Comment: Use array variables: set one to the files and the another to the folders. Loop over them.

Comment: As to the "tried to ask a question" part, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ L. Scott Johnson: Thank you for the tip about the array variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The result is, that the 3 files are in the 3rd folder.

You mean: the 1st folder? Why you choose fquantity=3 if you have only 3 files overall? It is files-per-folder quantity!

I tested that for loop, and it works so far. You have to choose the right "quantity" to distribute your files evenly into the dirs.

Your Q is really a bit hard to understand, with the file names you give and the quantity. And: 01.txt belongs into 01.abc, "but the names should not be considered".

You have, say, 3000 files that should be moved into 17 folders.  Or is it x folders each with max. of 200 files? This would be the first step, simple math and a loop with a counter.

Then come the questions of "robustness" (whitespace) and performance, and how to use standard commands to simplify the "program".

Your example:

```
for FOLDER in $FOLDERLIST; do mv `$LISTFILESCMD | head -n $FQUANTITY`   $FOLDER; done
```

is elegant in some way, because it doesn't need a filelist: it reads in the **remaining** (unmoved) files. And it should be fast enough, because you fill every folder only once, with one big `mv` command.

By choosing the right arg to `head` (fquantity) I could mv 7 files to 3 dirs as I want --- I thought I wanted 3-3-1. But if I choose quantity "7", I get all 7 files in the FIRST dir. With "1" I get 1-1-1, and four unmoved files. Ideal would be 3-2-2...so maybe the math involved is not even sooo simple.

But: a filename with whitespace is not moved, and it's parts are not found by `mv`. The author was surprised as it seems and commented: *oh, must be a whitespace problem*.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The files go into folder 1.
And also, my question is hard to understand.
I wanted to say, that the files should not be resorted by the command.

Thank you for your answer and the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with arrays should work even with files containing spaces, since you *did* quote the expansions properly. You might have trouble with filenames starting with dashes, though, use `mv -- file dir/` to prevent that (or put `./` in front of the globs: `./*` instead of `*` etc.).

As for picking only files, I don't think there's a way to do it directly in Bash (zsh could do it, though). But we can just pick a list of everything and filter the regular files from it:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=(*/)   # directories
tmp=(*)     # everything
files=()    # files

for f in "${tmp[@]}"; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        files+=("$f")
    fi
done

for ((i=0 ; i < ${#dirs[@]} ; ++i)); do
    mv -- "${files[i]}" "${dirs[i]}"
done
```

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you very much!